# Ant javac source/target options not working

Tags: java, ant, java-8, upgrade

I recently upgraded the java version for my application. When I ran my ant script which had javac set as:

```
<javac destdir="${build.dir}" target="${javac.target}" source="${javac.source}" debug="true" nowarn="${javac.nowarn}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" optimize="${javac.optimize}" encoding="${javac.encoding}" failonerror="true">
     <src path="${build.dir}" />
     <classpath refid="master-classpath" />
</javac>
```

When I run the the script with this, the project does not build properly.

So I changed it to:

```
<javac destdir="${build.dir}" target="1.8" source="1.8" debug="true" nowarn="${javac.nowarn}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" optimize="${javac.optimize}" encoding="${javac.encoding}" failonerror="true" sourcepath="">
    <src path="${java.src.dir}" />
    <classpath refid="master-classpath" />
</javac>
```

And ran the script, I get the error:

```
 [javac] javac: invalid target release: 1.8
 [javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
 [javac] use -help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: Most likely you are still using java 1.7.  Try debugging by printing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
    <property environment="env"/>
    <echo message="Java is ${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
Update your JAVA_HOME and/or PATH environment variables and start a new shell as needed.

Comment: @pamcevoy Yes, it is unfortunately. It is pointing to an even older 1.6. Can you tell me how to get the ant to point and use the new jdk8? Because JAVA HOME and PATH are all pointing to 1.8.

Comment: How are you launching the ant build?  If it's a shell, start a new shell with the environment variables correctly set and try again.  If it's some CI system, restart it from a shell with the correct environment variables.